# return full class with reducer statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rest-parameters

I'm getting the error:

"Type '{ permissions: any; avatarUrl: string; email: string; calendarStatus: string; roleID: number; lastLoginDate: DateType; mfa: boolean; availability: string | null; outOfOffice: any[]; ... 4 more ...; name: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': role, subtitle, searchField, link, and 3 more.ts(2740)"

with the following function:

```
const reducer = (state: User, action: { type: string, value: any | object }): User => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'roleChange':
      return { ...state, ...action.value }
    case 'permissionsChange':
      return { ...state, permissions: { ...state.permissions, ...action.value } }
    default:
      break
  }
  return state
}
```

The problem is with this line:

```
return { ...state, permissions: { ...state.permissions, ...action.value } }
```

My intention is return the full class, not a partial. I'm aware I can type it to return a Partial User, but this fix makes other parts of my code not workable, as I reference certain attributes on the User class.

Answer (score 0):

You're spreading the `action.value` instead of assigning a value to a property. Should look like this.

```
const reducer = (state: User, action: { type: string, value: any | object }): User => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'roleChange':
      return { ...state, ...action.value }
    case 'permissionsChange':
      return { ...state, permissions: action.value }
    default:
      break
  }
  return state
}
```

Or if you know the field inside permissions you want to update

```
const reducer = (state: User, action: { type: string, value: any | object }): User => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'roleChange':
      return { ...state, ...action.value }
    case 'permissionsChange':
      return { ...state, permissions: { ...state.permissions, someField: action.value } }
    default:
      break
  }
  return state
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you recommendation has fixed this issue as I'm still getting a similar with the following:
```
 case 'permissionsChange':
      return {
        ...state,
        permissions: {
        ...state.permissions,
        conversations_all: action.value.conversations_all,
        conversations_mine: action.value.conversations_mine,
        conversations_unclaimed: action.value.conversations_unclaimed
```

Comment: Need to clarify that, but I fixed the issue and gave you an idea, not the final solution as you didn't share enough information.